# Check if an instance of an application is open

Tags: c#

Could someone show how could I check if an instance of VS is open and if so I need to show a message.

```
 private String MSBUILD = File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe") == true 
    ? @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" 
    : @"C:\LegacyApp\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe";
```

This is my path to the VS directory. I need to check if it's open and if it's open I need to show a message that is saying you need to close the previous one before you open another.

Comment: Did you try `Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv.exe")` ? if returned array is not empty, then VS instance is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c# you can use "Process.GetProcessesByName()" for check if process is running. To see name of program use "Task Manager - Services".
Get current process-application name with "Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName".
Combining all will give you

bool isAlreadyWorking = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1;

Comment: and this will work only for one process ? I mean i only need to check the VS when another tool application is open.

Comment: then change "Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName" with <checkapplicationname>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I took the your advice and it work. I did some modification. So my final code looks like this for anyone who will wonder:                                    Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv.exe");                            if ( localByName.Count() > 1)

Answer (score 0):

When an application is running, it is called a process in the context of the operating system. In c# you can use the `Process.GetProcessById()`, `Process.GetProcessesByName()` .

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace check_if_process_is_running
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool isRunning(string name)
        {
            try { 
                Process.GetProcessByName(name); 
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException) { 
                return false; 
            }
            catch (ArgumentException) { 
                return false; 
            }
            return true;
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool running = isRunning("devenv.exe");
            if (running)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Running");
            }
        }
    }
}
```